# When passing a callback function, can you set a parameter?

Tags: javascript

I am passing a callback function as a parameter to a function, and I am doing this in various parts of my web app.

I want the callback to react a little differently in some cases, can I pass a parameter somehow to this callback?

```
soemethod(callback);
otherethod(callback);

otherother(callback(a=1));
```

How could I pass a=1 in the callback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use an anonymous function wrapped around your parameterized function call:

```
otherother(function () {
    callback(1); // assuming the first parameter is called a
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

But you can do something like this:

```
    soemethod(callback);
    otherethod(callback);

    otherother(callback, 1);


function otherother(callback, defaultValue) {
    var value = defaultValue;

    // your logic here, ie.
    if(someCondition)
       value = 2;

    callback(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others already mentioned, you can't pass default parameters like that in Javascript - you have to create the separate function yourself.

What you *can* do however, is use some very neat helper functions to create these closures automatically for you. One of the patterns I like the most is [partial function application](http://ejohn.org/blog/partial-functions-in-javascript/), where the "default" parameters are the leftmost parameters.

If you are using a new browser you can use [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (it also handles the `this` parameter - this can allow passing methods as callbacks as well)

```
 otherother( callback.bind(undefined, 1) );
 //sets the first parameter to 1
 //when the callback is called, the 2nd, 3rd, parameters are filled and so on
```

If you need to support older browsers as well, it is not hard to [create your own](http://ejohn.org/blog/partial-functions-in-javascript/) partial application functions (lots of JS frameworks have one of some sort, the next example was taken from Prototype)

```
  Function.prototype.curry = function() {
    var fn = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return function() {
      return fn.apply(this, args.concat(
        Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
    };
  };
```